# Auto reload file and in neovim and auto reload nerbtree

Tags: neovim

I'm using `neovim` for coding C++. I have some trouble when coding with it.

I often use file to read and write data. When I run C++ file by command `g++ -o data data.cpp && ./data`, output file don't reload in neovim.

I try use

```
set autoread 
au CursorHold * checktime
```

but it doesn't work.

I don't want to type `:e` to reload everytime I run code

Additionally, I want to know how to set auto reload `nerbtreee` when I create new file or folder on Explorer.

Environment:

```
nvim: 0.4.3
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it.

Thanks for **spacetime-continuum** on Reddit

This is how I configure for this problem:

```
    " trigger `autoread` when files changes on disk
      set autoread
      autocmd FocusGained,BufEnter,CursorHold,CursorHoldI * if mode() != 'c' | checktime | endif
    " notification after file change
      autocmd FileChangedShellPost *
        \ echohl WarningMsg | echo "File changed on disk. Buffer reloaded." | echohl None
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, is there something else that has to be added to init.vim?

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I auto-read buffers using `lua` [Config](https://github.com/pr7prashant/neovim/blob/9ee542bb95492a6c2fe2eb5ba0874a4b00f7aedd/lua/user/autocommands.lua#L48)

```lua
vim.o.autoread = true
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufEnter", "CursorHold", "CursorHoldI", "FocusGained" }, {
  command = "if mode() != 'c' | checktime | endif",
  pattern = { "*" },
})
```

Comment: thank you this helped me solve the problem

Comment: I added `vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "FileChangedShellPost" }, {
    command = 'echohl WarningMsg | echo "File changed on disk. Buffer reloaded." | echohl None',
    pattern = { "*" },
})` to copy the warning message suggested by @lewis-tran above